# Django-Compressor Compressed Filename

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

Working with Django-compressor.  Wondering if there's anyway to get the compressed filename so that I can load the script asynchronously (as django-compressor currently doesn't support that).

**E.g.** So I can do something like this in my template

```
var compressed = {{ COMPRESSED_JS_FILENAME|undefined }};
if (compressed) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = compressed;
    script.setAttribute('async', True);
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
}
```

**Python Version**: 2.7
**Django Version**: 1.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative Solution**:

Couldn't find a way to do this, so instead I added hook for the page to go over the tags and basically look for the ones that had been compressed and add an async tag to them.
Psuedocode/Idea

```
content = BeautifulSoup(page)
scripts = [tag.extract() for tag in soup.find_all('script')]
for script in scripts:
    old_script = script
    src = script.get('src')
    if '/COMPRESSED/' in src:
        script['async'] = "True"
    page = page.replace(old_script, script)
```